# Does vim have functionality for completetion of methods/variables with punctuation?

Tags: autocompletion, filetype-ruby

In Ruby, and languages based on Ruby the style-guide recommends bool getter methods be named `empty?` as opposed to `is_empty`. Note the question mark.

Vim however, does not complete the `?` by default. Is there a setting to enable this? Or a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

The [`iskeyword`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27iskeyword%27) setting controls this. You can add `?` and `!` to it with:

```
:setlocal iskeyword+=? iskeyword+=!
```

Or, for just Ruby from your vimrc:

```
augroup ruby_settings
    autocmd!
    autocmd Filetype Ruby :setlocal iskeyword+=? iskeyword+=!
augroup end
```

Do **not** use `set iskeyword=..` from your vimrc, as that will likely lead to problems with other filetypes.

---

The `iskeyword` setting is used for many commands; for example:

- `dw` would previously delete up to a `?`, but now it will *also* delete the `?`.
- `gf` will now also match `?`, so `gf` on `# is this file correct: a.rb?` will try to open `a.rb?` (which won't exist).
- `*` will match the word with question-mark.

There are many more cases; the above list is not exhaustive. Some of these behaviours could be considered features, others might be considered bugs. Personally, I've learned to not frob with `iskeyword` too much (in part because I like my `dw` etc. to behave the same regardless of filetype), but others like to modify it extensively.

Just remember: if you run into *Weird Problems*™ later on then your frobbery with the `iskeyword` setting could very well be the cause!